# GCloud SDK - Shared VPC - Associate only a specific network when attaching a project using gcloud SDK

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-networking

Is there a way to share a specific subnet of a Shared VPC to a project using the gcloud SDK?

I can use the below command to associate a project but it shares all of the host project's subnets and it doesn't appear there is a flag to specify a specific subnet from the host project to share to the service project.

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/shared-vpc/associated-projects/add

Answer (score 0):

In this case you could achieve this as a Shared VPC Admin whom can define an IAM member from a service project as a Service Project Admin with access to only [some of the subnets](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/provisioning-shared-vpc#networkuseratsubnet) in the host project.

Hope this works for you.